# How can I create a pool of objects in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, pool

I need to dispatch incoming requests to a set of connected services (say a `Service` class) in a balanced manner (sending an equal number of requests to each service).

I thought I can do this similar to how database connection pools are used, so I implemented a simple pool:

```py
from service import Service

class ServicePool:
    services: list[Service]
    index: int

    def __init__(self, services: list[Service]):
        self.index = 0
        self.services = services

    def get_next(self) -> Service:
        try:
            return self.services[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            return None
        finally:
            if self.index < len(self.services) - 1:
                self.index += 1
            else:
                self.index = 0
```

I have several questions:

1. Am I overthinking this? Is there a simple data structure that I can use in the standard library?
2. Is this a good idea in general?

Comment: What's the problem? Your approach seems reasonable.

Comment: Since Python objects are not multithreaded on its own, is there any benefit of having several objects and distribute work among them? If you have implemented multithreading elsewhere, wouldn't you need to synchronize access to the pool?

Comment: @mkrieger1 my implementation of pool seems naive.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The services are actually third-party APIs with different endpoints in this case.

Comment: In a database pool, you normally ask for the next **available** connection and return it to the pool when done. You could use a queue for that: you ask for the next element of the queue and return it to the end of the queue when done.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pool of objects in Python, you can try this library:

Pond is a high performance object-pooling library for Python, it has a smaller memory usage and a higher borrow hit rate.

https://github.com/T-baby/pondpond

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32866960)